# MPICH issue with explicit instantiation(ignoring extern)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, mpich, mpic++

I wrote a simple c++ program using explicit instantiation technique as below:

```
// foo.hpp
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
  template <typename Arg>
  static void call(Arg arg)
  {
    std::cout << "foo\n";
  }
};
```

here I have the explicit instantiation of class foo:

```
// foo.cc
#include "foo.hpp"
template void foo::call(int);
```

and in the main file I use the **extern** keyword to tell the compiler the **foo::call** is already instantiated, so there is no need to compile it again:

```
// main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.hpp"

extern template void foo::call(int);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  foo::call(1);

  return 0;
}
```

I test the program with **g++** and **mpic++** using **gcc-4.9**. 
For **g++** when I pass the **foo.o** it works fine:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c foo.cc
g++ -std=c++11 main.cc foo.o -o main
```

and when I don't pass the **foo.o** it complains as expected:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test_simple.cc -o test_simple 
/tmp/ccclcKnc.o: In function `main':
test_simple.cc:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `void foo::call<int>      
(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but when I compile with **mpic++** (MPICH) in both cases(either passing or not passing the **foo.o**) the program compiles which should complain when the **foo.o** is not passed.

```
mpic++ -std=c++11 -c foo.cc
mpic++ -std=c++11 main.cc foo.o -o main
```

or

```
mpic++ -std=c++11 main.cc -o main // this line shouldn't compile but it does
```

I tested the code with **OpenMPI** and the behavior is same as **g++**. So the question is why the **MPICH** ignores the **extern** and compiles the instantiation again.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure which behavior to expect now that g++ and ld are smart enough to handle multiple template instantiations without complaining about doubly defined symbols. Did you try to let mpic++ show the flags that it passes down to the compiler/linker as explained on its man page (--showme)?

Comment: @GeorgBisseling I guess the --shwme flag is only for OpenMPI, not MPICH.

Comment: The option for MPICH is `-show`.